# Understanding imports / use in PHPUnit

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

Within a PHPUnit test, I am trying to get all classes of my symfony application that implement a certain interface. My application code lives in namespace `App`, my tests in `Tests`.

This TestCase Code does only list a class **if I instantiate (or "use")** it (the `use` statements on top have no effect):

```
namespace Tests\ReportPlaceholder;

use App\ReportPlaceholder\LimitModificationsPlaceholder;
use App\ReportPlaceholder\SimpleEvaluatePlaceholder;
use App\ReportPlaceholder\ReportPlaceholderInterface;

class MyTest extends KernelTestCase{


    public function provider(){

        new SimpleEvaluatePlaceholder(); // <-- if I comment this line, the class is *not* found
        // also a usage of SimpleEvaluatePlaceholder::class suffices

        return array_map(function($p) { return [$p]; }, 
                array_filter(get_declared_classes(), function($className){
                     return in_array(ReportPlaceholderInterface::class, class_implements($className));}
        ));
    }
}
```

`provider` returns in this scenario only `SimpleEvaluatePlaceholder`

My composer.json is

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
```

and the phpunit.xml reads:

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/6.5/phpunit.xsd"
     backupGlobals="false"
     colors="true"
     bootstrap="config/bootstrap.php"
     verbose="true"
     debug="false"
     stopOnFailure="true">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is similar to what @peetya supposed: I have to boot an additional kernel in `provider` to fetch the service list (and immediately after that close it again):

```
public function provider()
{
    $ret = [];
    self::bootKernel();
    foreach (static::$container->get('report_helper')->placeholders as $placeholder){
        /** @var $placeholder ReportPlaceholderInterface */
        $ret[] = [get_class($placeholder)];
    }
    static::ensureKernelShutdown();
    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `KernelTestCase`, you have access to the Container, where you can easily achieve it by tagging all your services which implements your interface and passing them to a Registry service on the following way *(Symfony 3.4 or higher)*:

```
# services.yml
services:
  _instanceof:
    YourInterface:
      tags: ['my_custom_tag']

  App\Registry\MyCustomTagRegistry:
    arguments: [!tagged my_custom_tag]
```

Your Registry class:

```
class MyCustomTagRegistry
{
  /** @var Traversable */
  private $services;

  public function __construct(iterable $services = [])
  {
    $this->services = $services;
  }

  public function getServices(): array
  {
    return (array) $this->services;
  }
}
```

Then in your test you need to fetch the given service from the container:

```
$services = self::$container->get(MyCustomTagRegistry::class)->getServices();
```

You can find here more details how to work with service tags:

- https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html#reference-tagged-services
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html#autoconfiguring-tags

Comment: This solution is perfect, apart from the fact that the data provider is called **before** `setUp` where the kernel and container is built. But I could try to boot a dummy kernel in the data provider just to get a service that exposes the tagged services...

Comment: Why don't you boot your kernel in the `setUp`?

Comment: i am in fact doing this, but the data provider is called once before all test function and also before each `setUp` call https://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers

Comment: If your Dataprovider is called before the `setUp` maybe you could fetch the services in the `setUp` after boot and store them in an array on instance level (`$this->services = self::$container->get(MyCustomTagRegistry::class)->getServices();`), and instead of using dataprovider, you could just simply loop through on this array in your test.

Comment: Yes, I guess such a workaround is ok. I should just accept that fetching data from the container in a data provider is not a good test design. Thanks  to all! Closing here